# AngularFirestore Dynamic Querying

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

I'm using Angular 9.0.4 and Firestore Database and I have some instructors with different locations and category of subject. The concept is that I will select my location and the subject I want (ex. Athens and Maths) and I will take back the instructors with those values. I found AngularFire to do that, but some the "combineLatest" operator that I need is deprecated and despite how hard I'm trying to convert the documentation code with the latest Rxjs I can't find a solution. Below is my code.

> home.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {combineLatest, of} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


export interface Instructors {
  last_name: string;
  location: string;
  cate: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  instructors$: Observable<Instructors[]>;
  locationFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;
  cateFilter$: BehaviorSubject<string | null>;


  constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.locationFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.cateFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.instructors$ = combineLatest(
      this.locationFilter$,
      this.cateFilter$
    ).map(([location, cate]) =>
      afs.collection<Instructors>('items', ref => {
        let query: firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
        if (location) {
          query = query.where('location', '==', location);
        }
        if (cate) {
          query = query.where('cate', '==', cate);
        }
        return query;
      }).valueChanges()
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  filterByLocation(location: string | null) {
    this.locationFilter$.next(location);
  }

  filterByCate(cate: string | null) {
    this.cateFilter$.next(cate);
  }

}
```

> home.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="instructors$ | async; let instructors; else loading">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let instructor of instructors">
      {{ instructor.last_name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div *ngIf="instructors.length === 0">No results, try clearing filters</div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading&hellip;</ng-template>
<div>
  <h4>Filter by</h4>
  <div>
    <h5>Size</h5>
    <button (click)="filterByLocation('Thessaloniki')">Thessaloniki</button>
    <button (click)="filterByLocation('Crete')">Crete</button>
    <button (click)="filterByLocation(null)" *ngIf="this.locationFilter$.getValue()">
      <em>clear filter</em>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h5>Color</h5>
    <button (click)="filterByCate('Leadership')">Leadership</button>
    <button (click)="filterByCate('Maths')">Maths</button>
    <button (click)="filterByCate(null)" *ngIf="this.cateFilter$.getValue()">
      <em>clear filter</em>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> firestore database be like

```
instructors{

      randomId{

     name: string;
     cate: string;
     location: string;

     }
}
```

Comment: Upload a sample to stackblitz.com and edit your question with a very specific question. I cannot understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: The combineLatest operator is not deprecated. Only the use of it. You need to pass the arguments into a single array like so ```combineLatest([this.locationFilter$, this.cateFilter$])```. You should also move the logic from the component's constructor into a service in order to follow the best practices.

Comment: @ionut-t  Thanks for your answer. I tried this but still doesn't work. Can you give me more details? Also I have in mind to create a service for this, I just wanted to make it work asap and then polish it.

Comment: @pavlidisnick First thing first! Have you created a composite index? If not then you should get an error in the dev console. Click on it and you'll be directed to the firebase console where you can create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `map` operator in your code but you need to subscribe to a new stream and in that case, you need to use the `switchMap` operator. Starting with RxJS 6.0 (if I'm not mistaken) you need to use pipeable operators.

The following code should work:

```
this.instructors$ = combineLatest([this.locationFilter$, this.cateFilter$]).pipe(
      switchMap(([location, cate]) =>
        afs
          .collection<Instructors>('items', ref => {
            let query: firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
            if (location) {
              query = query.where('location', '==', location);
            }
            if (cate) {
              query = query.where('cate', '==', cate);
            }
            return query;
          })
          .valueChanges()
      )
    );
```

Note: You can also use `mergeMap` and `flatMap` instead of `switchMap`. You can read more about them and the difference between them [here](https://rxjs.dev/api).

Comment: What if I have a collection "locations" with only names and I want to check if locations.name = instructors.location

Comment: You can use the same logic that you've already written. Just create a method where you pass as an argument the instructor location and query by that.

Comment: If is not urgent, I can give you a help. Unfortunately, these days my calendar is quite full.

Comment: I was searching your email cause I was really stuck and thought to sent from your website form but luckily someone helped me. But thanks you are really kind.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you managed to overcome that challenge. Happy coding